# API Token Authentication - Security issue

Tags: rest, api, asp.net-web-api

For token based authentication for any service, first we have to send username/password in the request. Doesn't this cause security issue? How can we overcome this security issue of passing username/password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial request which contains the username and password is no more or less secure than subsequent requests which would instead be bearing some sort of token.  The solution to this problem, really to sending *any* type of information across the network, is to use two way SSL/HTTPS.  With HTTPS, information being sent gets encrypted on the client machine, and then (in theory) only the server would be able to read what is contained.  So, sending the plain text username and password might seem insecure, but if using HTTPS, then in fact it is secure.